# How to properly form a possessive case?

Tags: possessives

Let's say we have following cases:

- Color of death
- Death's color
- Death color

Trying to answer the question "What color the death is?" which case is the right one?
And what is the difference between all of them?
When I need to use one or another?

Comment: "What color the death is?" isn't a grammatically correct question.  The correct version would be "What color is the death?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that *color of death* is the right choice.

If you are referring to Death as a person (like in 'Tales of Beedle the Bard'), *Death's color* would work. *Death color* does not sound right to me. Unless you have already established that death has a color (say 'black'), in which case case you could say that 'something was *death colored*'